# dynamically create delegate for ctor

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I'm trying to create generic factory class. Since Activator.CreateInstance is pretty slow, I decided to use delegates. The goal was call constructor any public constructor, regardless of parameters count. So I was going like this:

```
public void Register<VType>(TKey key, params object[] args) where VType : TType
    {
        ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(VType).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.HasThis, args.Select(a => a.GetType()).ToArray(), new ParameterModifier[] { });
        if (ci == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Constructor for type '{0}' was not found.", typeof(VType)));


        var pExp = Expression.Parameter(args.GetType());
        var ctorParams = ci.GetParameters();
        var expArr = new Expression[ctorParams.Length];
        var p = new ParameterExpression[ctorParams.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < ctorParams.Length; i++)
        {
            var ctorType = ctorParams[i].ParameterType;
            var pName = ctorParams[i].Name;
            var argExp = Expression.ArrayIndex(pExp, Expression.Constant(i));
            var argExpConverted = Expression.Convert(argExp, ctorType);
            expArr[i] = argExpConverted;
            p[i] = Expression.Parameter(args[i].GetType(), pName);
        }

        var foo = Expression.Lambda(Expression.New(ci, expArr), p);

        Delegate constructorDelegate = foo.Compile();

        FactoryMap.Add(key, constructorDelegate);
    }
```

And then - call delegate in Create method. With no parameters all goes well, but when I'm adding some - I'm getting InvalidOperationException - "variable '' of type 'System.Object[]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined", after foo.Compile() call. 
Why? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, how would you handle NULL values in your object array ? suppose you  have two constructors: first constructor accepts a string for first parameter and second constructor accepts a StringBuilder. But you will pass NULL for this argument. How would you know wich constructor to call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a class that exposes an extention method that gives you a delegate for creating an instance of type T by calling the constructor that binds to specified paramArguments types.

```
public static class ConstructorCallExcentions
{
    private static Dictionary<ConstructorInfo, Func<Object[], Object>> _constructors = new Dictionary<ConstructorInfo,Func<object[],object>> ();
    private static object syncObject = new object();

    public static Func<Object[], Object> CreateConstructor<T>(this T @this, params Type[] paramArguments)
    {

        ConstructorInfo cInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(paramArguments);
        if (cInfo == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Could not detect constructor having the coresponding parameter types");

        Func<Object[], Object> ctor;
        if (false == _constructors.TryGetValue (cInfo, out ctor))
        {
            lock (_constructors)
            {
                if (false == _constructors.TryGetValue (cInfo, out ctor))
                {
                    // compile the call

                    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "arguments");

                    List<Expression> argumentsExpressions = new List<Expression>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < paramArguments.Length; i++)
                    {

                        var indexedAcccess = Expression.ArrayIndex(parameterExpression, Expression.Constant(i));

                        // it is NOT a reference type!
                        if (paramArguments [i].IsClass == false && paramArguments [i].IsInterface == false)
                        {
                            // it might be the case when I receive null and must convert to a structure. In  this case I must put default (ThatStructure).
                            var localVariable = Expression.Variable(paramArguments[i], "localVariable");

                            var block = Expression.Block (new [] {localVariable},
                                    Expression.IfThenElse (Expression.Equal (indexedAcccess, Expression.Constant (null)),
                                        Expression.Assign (localVariable, Expression.Default (paramArguments [i])),
                                        Expression.Assign (localVariable, Expression.Convert(indexedAcccess, paramArguments[i]))
                                    ),
                                    localVariable
                                );

                            argumentsExpressions.Add(block);

                        }
                        else
                            argumentsExpressions.Add(Expression.Convert(indexedAcccess, paramArguments[i])); // do a convert to that reference type. If null, the convert is FINE.
                    }

                    // check if parameters length maches the length of constructor parameters!
                    var lengthProperty = typeof (Object[]).GetProperty ("Length");
                    var len = Expression.Property (parameterExpression, lengthProperty);
                    var invalidParameterExpression = typeof(ArgumentException).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });

                    var checkLengthExpression = Expression.IfThen (Expression.NotEqual (len, Expression.Constant (paramArguments.Length)),
                        Expression.Throw(Expression.New(invalidParameterExpression, Expression.Constant ("The length does not match parameters number")))
                        );

                    var newExpr = Expression.New(cInfo, argumentsExpressions);

                    var finalBlock = Expression.Block(checkLengthExpression, Expression.Convert(newExpr, typeof(Object)));

                    _constructors[cInfo] = ctor = Expression.Lambda(finalBlock, new[] { parameterExpression }).Compile() as Func<Object[], Object>;
                }
            }
        }

        return ctor;
    }
}
```

To use it, for example supose you have this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(string s, int h)
    {
        Console.Write("aaa");
    }
}
```

Then write this code:

```
var ctor = default(Test).CreateConstructor(typeof(string), typeof(int));


var newlyObject = ctor(new object[] { "john", 22 });
```

From your example, I saw that your intentions are to use the Delegate to invoke later any constructor. Instead of using Delegate and the DynamicInvoke API, use my

```
Func <Object[], Object>.
```

Why? Here is a couple of advantages that I have in mind right now:

1) DynamicInvoke is much slower than calling a direct typed delegate.

2) DynamicInvoke will break any stack trace in case of an exception. What I mean is that whenever an exception is thrown in the constructor, you will receive a TargetInvocationException instead of the real exception that happened. You can inspect the InnerException of that TargetInvocationException but ... clear is more work to do. Calling directly the typed delegate Func will save you from this issue.

Happy coding!

Comment: This is great! Thank you George.

Comment: Why the dictionary and lockobject? Thats why you have concurrentdictionary, no?

Comment: The dictionary stands as a cache for constructor delegates and the lock ensures that there will not be problems into a multithreading environment. The concurrent dictionary does not help. Imagine that two threads enter. First checks for existance (try get value) and the second one waits. When the first thread exits, the second one enters and checks again. Both threads will consider that there is no entry in the dictionary so they both will proceed creating a new lambda. Concurrent dict are themselves thread safe but not "environmental" thread safe

Comment: To continue with my response. A "transaction" over a ConcurrentDictionary composes by two operations: an check for existance followed by an add operation is not thread safe. Normally you can call TryAdd but this works only if you already have the object to add or is cheap to create it, otherwise (like my case in wich i must build and expression and compile it) i must fallback to more classical coding style

Comment: +1 for using `Expression.Default` for `null` to value-type conversion. Was actually trying to convert `ConstructorInfo` with default arguments to `Func<object>` and came across some having `HasDefaultValue = true`, but `IsOptional = false`, `DefaultValue = null` but `ParameterType = typeof(int)`. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, thank you.